# IllegalStateException using getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable()

Tags: java, android

I am using an Activity as a Dialog in my app and inside the `onCreate` method I am using **`getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable()`** but it give me **`illegalStateException`** mostly on oreo devices.

## Here is my `DialogActivity` Code:

```
ImageButton btnStop,btnCancel;
Handler handler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog);
    this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);

    btnCancel=findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
    btnStop=findViewById(R.id.btnStopAlarm);
    btnStop.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(this);


    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
}
```

**here is my DialogActivity crash report**

[image: here is my crash report]

[image: here is my crash report]

Comment: So you want background transparent for your dialogActivity?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide the complete stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing seems to be wrong with your code. If you can't find the reason you can set it through styles. Define the following in your `styles.xml` file:

```
<style name="MyActivityStyle" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Now just set it to your Manifest where you declare your activity:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.myproject.mypackage.MyActivity"
        android:theme="@style/MyActivityStyle" />
```

Answer (score 0):

When does this happen? Is it after a button press or before?
if it is after you would want to set all attributes of the dialog window before inflating it.
Place the code:

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

before:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog)
```

EDIT: I had the same problem whenever the dialog window was cancelled, i found out in my case the context of the application was null every time this happened.

Comment: Actually my DialogActivity start by broadCast receiver in other class just by calling a simple activity like **Intent open =new Intent(this,DialogActivity);** and then **startActivity(open);**

Comment: You need to provide a stack trace, as requested by Mike. Make sure you use debugging techniques, like breakpoints before and after the exception so that you may know where the exception occurs in the code.